# How to write/read variables from files and parse using Makefile?

Tags: gcc, makefile, gnu-make, nmake

How can I write or read variables from a config file using a Makefile in Windows with GNU Make?

The contents of a build config for a Makefile:
`FLAGS_ARCH: X64; FLAGS_TYPE: RELEASE;`

```
FILE_CONFIG        = `cat c:\\build.config`
#FLAGS_ARCH        = 
#FLAGS_TYPE        =

SET:
    #how to set?

GET:
    @echo ARCH: $(FLAGS_ARCH); TYPE: $(FLAGS_TYPE);
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem have a Windows filesystem with a Unix-like environment. So assuming
you've got the `sed` command, you could do this like so:

**Makefile**

```
FILE_CONFIG := build.config

.PHONY: SET GET

SET: FLAGS_ARCH ?= X64
SET: FLAGS_TYPE ?= RELEASE
SET:
    @echo "FLAGS_ARCH: $(FLAGS_ARCH); FLAGS_TYPE: $(FLAGS_TYPE);" > $(FILE_CONFIG) 


GET: CONFIG = $(shell sed -e 's/://g' -e 's/;//g' $(FILE_CONFIG))
GET: FLAGS_ARCH = $(word 2,$(CONFIG))
GET: FLAGS_TYPE = $(word 4,$(CONFIG))
GET:
    @echo "ARCH: $(FLAGS_ARCH); TYPE: $(FLAGS_TYPE);";
```

Set defaults:

```
$ make SET
```

Get what we just set:

```
$ make GET
ARCH: X64; TYPE: RELEASE;
```

Set some non-defaults:

```
$ make SET FLAGS_ARCH=i386 FLAGS_TYPE=DEBUG
```

Get them:

```
$ make GET
ARCH: i386; TYPE: DEBUG;
```

You could do without `sed` and just use `cat` and [`make` text-functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Text-Functions.html),
but it takes more rigmarole.

In this makefile, `FLAGS_ARCH` and `FLAGS_TYPE` are [*target-specific variables*](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Target_002dspecific.html).
They each have one definition for the target `SET`, and a different definition for the target `GET`, and otherwise no definition.

This makefile will tolerate spaces preceding the punctuators `:` and `;`